# Reducing this matrix to row echelon form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to reduce this matrix to row echelon form. I've tried a bunch of different operations and can't seem to figure it out.

```
   1  1  1
   1  2 -1
   1  3  2
```

I tried R2 = R1 + R2, R2 = R2 - R3, R3 = R3- -(R2) which resulted in:

```
   1   1   1
   1   0  -2
   0   3   0
```

Not sure where I can go from here, looking for some help.

I'm looking for a zero row to determine if this linear system if dependent (zero row exists) or indepedent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, reducing matrices by hand is best done algorithmically, rather than trying to find "clever steps" to expedite the process. For example: 
$R2-R1$ and $R3-R1$ will give you the first column.

\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 1 & 1 \\
    0       & 1 & -2  \\
    0       & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Now, if we can go ahead and get rid of the $1,2$ in the middle column by doing $R1-R2=R1$ $R3-2R2=R3$, since there is a $0$ in the first column of $R2$! We obtain:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 3 \\
    0       & 1 & -2  \\
    0       & 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}

Since we are here, might as well finish the job:

$R1=R1-3/5(R3)$ and $R2=R2+2/5(R3)$. Then $R3=1/5(R3)$ and we get the desired result:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 1 & 0  \\
    0       & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

What does this tell you? (this is also well beyond just row echelon form.)

Answer (score 0):

R2=R2-R1, R3=R3-R1 result in :

```
1   1   1
0   1  -2
0   2   1
```

Then R3=R3-2R2 results in:

```
1   1   1
0   1  -2
0   0   5
```